# Which Timer to use in this context

Tags: c#

I have a `do/while` like the following:

```
do {

  //1.look for a report

  //2.either use interops to run an xl macro report or run a batch file report or run vbs file report

  //3.then sleep/pause program for 150seconds 

} while (look for next report to run)
```

This is all withing a `Console` application.

How do I create the 150 second pause/sleep ? Step 2 might involve running various processes and I'm slightly worried that simply using `Thread.Sleep` might be troublesome as it is not thread safe.

---

Should I somehow work this sort of code into the structure i.e. put steps 1 and 2 in the `CallMeBack` method?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += (s, e) => CallMeBack();
    t.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static void CallMeBack() {

    //1.look for a report
    //2.either use interops to run an xl macro report or run a batch file report or run vbs file report

    Console.WriteLine("Doing some consuming time work using sleep");
}
```

(the above is taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430930/c-sharp-how-to-pause-suspend-a-thread-then-continue-it))

Comment: The general approach looks just fine.  Note that rather than a `while` loop you'll have an `if(something){timer.Stop();}`.

Comment: In this implementation the call will happen once every 150 seconds, regardless of how long your operation took.

Comment: @Servy ... would you be ok putting your idea as a solution; I could do with seeing the pattern more fully?

Comment: How would sleeping a thread not be thread-safe? Just pause that single thread. Please specify requirements like this beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in millisecond, you can catch it in case it gets interrupted, but that usually does not happen.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150000);
```

Edit:

Another option is to use join if you simply want to wait till others are done or if you want to execute once every 150 seconds, your own answer would work. Make sure you know what you want before asking.

If you want thread-safe pause use:

```
task.Wait(150000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a loop. Steps 1 and 2 would be done inside an event that fires with the interval you specify.

If you need to have a semi-regular timer, you can set the Timer object to not auto-reset and enable it manually at the end of the event instead.

Comment: did you see the additional code I added to the OP; is something like that what you had in mind